# Router doesn't navigate to the detail page of the SplitApp

Tags: routes, sapui5

Hello,

I'm trying to implement routing on SplitApp (for now - navigation between master and detail pages).

I have a master view and 2 detail views.

The app is rendered, but when I try to navigate between the detail views, nothing happens.

Here is my routing definition from the `manifest.json` file:

```js
"routing": {
    "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
        "viewType": "XML",
        "viewPath": "qv.view",
        "controlId": "splitApp",
        "controlAggregation": "detailPages",
    },
    "routes": [{
        "pattern": "",
        "name": "master",
        "target": [ "detail", "master" ]
    }, {
        "pattern": "",
        "name": "detail",
        "target": [ "detail", "master" ]
    }, {
        "pattern": "",
        "name": "detail1",
        "target": "detail1"
    }],
    "targets": {
        "master": {
            "viewName": "Master",
            "viewLevel": 1,
            "viewId": "master",
            "controlAggregation": "masterPages"
        },
        "detail": {
            "viewName": "Detail",
            "viewId": "detail",
            "viewLevel": 2
        },
        "detail1": {
            "viewName": "Detail1",
            "viewId": "detail1",
            "viewLevel": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my app view's code:

```js
<mvc:View controllerName="qv.controller.View1" 
          xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
          xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
          xmlns="sap.m">

    <SplitApp id="splitApp">
    </SplitApp>

</mvc:View>
```

And here is my navigation function which resides in the controller of the master view:

```js
onSelectionChange: function(oEvent){
    var sPath = oItem.getBindingContext().getPath();
    var sTargetPage = this.getView().getModel().getProperty(sPath+"/targetPage");
    var oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();

    oRouter.navTo(sTargetPage);
}
```

The model is also very simple (it is defined in the master controller's `onInit` method):

```js
var oData = {
    "Menu": [{
        "title": "Detail page 1",
        "targetPage": "detail",
        "description": "This is the 1st detail page"
    }, {
        "title": "Detail page 2",
        "targetPage": "detail1",
        "description": "This is the 2nd detail page"
    }]
};
this.getView().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData));
```

The router is initialized, I do get it in `onSelectionChange` method.

What did I miss/did wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding patterns for the detail pages to the `manifest.json` file solved the problem:

```js
...
"routes": [
                {
                    "pattern": "",
                    "name": "master",
                    "target": [
                        "detail",
                        "master"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "detail",
                    "name": "detail",
                    "target": [
                        "detail",
                        "master"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "detail1",
                    "name": "detail1",
                    "target": "detail1"
                }
            ],
...
```